# top margin not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey there trying to put space between a button and header but for some reason no matter what value I put in top margin the two aren't separating.

I used bootstrap to build the button, below is the relevant HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="section banner">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Always have the answer to "What's for dinner?"</h3>
    <a class="btn-lg btn-default" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Banner */
.banner, .supporting {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.banner {
  background-color:#36343f;
  height:180px; 
  color: #fff;
}

.banner a {
  background-color: rgba(216,25,47,.5);
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.banner a:hover {
   background-color: rgba(216,25,47,1);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Everytime I change: `margin-top:` nothing happens. Since `.banner a {` changes the color of the button I would expect its margin property to work as well.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: However if I use .banner h3 { margin-bottom:30px } it works how come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give `display: block;` to `.banner a` will make working `margin-top`. Because anchor default `display:inline`

```
.banner a {
  background-color: rgba(216,25,47,.5);
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:block;
}
```

You can adjust some width also to decrease the width. And to make center give `text-align:center` to it's parent.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfae9d9y/)**

**Edit:**

If you don't want button to be long use. `display: inline-block;` instead of `display:block`.

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pfae9d9y/1/)**

Comment: For some reason that makes the button really long.. which I don't want

Comment: @jordan121sa check edited answer. Use `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cover the text by adding a extra div. Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2w3p1apd/)

```css
/* Banner */
.banner, .supporting {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.banner {
  background-color:#36343f;
  height:180px; 
  color: #fff;
}

.banner a {
  background-color: rgba(216,25,47,.5);
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.banner a:hover {
   background-color: rgba(216,25,47,1);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

/*modification*/
.middle{
  padding:50px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="section banner">
  <div class="container">
  
    <!-- MODIFICATION-------->
  <div class= "middle">
    <h3>Always have the answer to "What's for dinner?"</h3>
    </div>
    
    <!----------------------->
    <a class="btn-lg btn-default" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok but why is that necesary?

Comment: because you asked that you want to add space between button"Learn more" and header"Always have the answer to "What's for dinner?" isn't it? you can achieve by doing this

Comment: I understand but can you explain why html doesn't acknowledge <h3> and <a> as different blocks of code which can be separated by margins?